# How to write a minimalistic Java Client for OpenMQ

Tags: java, openmq

Please help an MQ nubee to write his first Java Client, I got a little bit lost in the Oracle docs.
I have OpenMQ up and running.
In the OpenMQ Administration Console I established a broker named "MyFirstTest"
1 of 6 services is "jms" (which seems to be the most easy to use service), this service is up and running, too (saying: Service state running).
So I come to the interesting part.
How do I connect to the broker "MyFirstTest", then to send a message in, and last but least read this message perhaps from a second client.

I think I have to find the already existing queue instead of using
new com.sun.messaging.Queue

Any example or link to is appreciated.

```
public class HelloWorldMessage {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ConnectionFactory myConnFactory;
        Queue myQueue;

        myConnFactory = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();
        Connection myConn = myConnFactory.createConnection();
        Session mySess = myConn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        myQueue = new com.sun.messaging.Queue("MyFirstTest");

        //Create a message producer.
        MessageProducer myMsgProducer = mySess.createProducer(myQueue);

        //Create and send a message to the queue.
        TextMessage myTextMsg = mySess.createTextMessage();
        myTextMsg.setText("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Sending Message: " + myTextMsg.getText());
        myMsgProducer.send(myTextMsg);

        //Create a message consumer.
        MessageConsumer myMsgConsumer = mySess.createConsumer(myQueue);

        //Start the Connection created in step 3.
        myConn.start();

        //Receive a message from the queue.
        Message msg = myMsgConsumer.receive();

        //Retreive the contents of the message.
        if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage) msg;
            System.out.println("Read Message: " + txtMsg.getText());
        }

        //Close the session and connection resources.
        mySess.close();
        myConn.close();

    } catch (Exception jmse) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred : " + jmse.toString());
        jmse.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code? There is a lot of examples on the net how to create a JMS publisher or subscriber (it doesn't have to be OpenMQ-specific).

Comment: I tried the HelloWorldMessage example. But the example uses a new message queue.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) post some code please

Comment: Ok, I added the code example above. The example uses a NEW queue instead of the existing one.

Comment: @Alex004 where did you get this example? There are a couple of things that are done wrong. First of all, instead of creating the `Queue` object directly, you should use `Session.createQueue()` method. Irrespective of that , the code creates the queue only if it doesn't exist yet, otherwise the existing one is used.

Comment: I found examples at Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1796/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assuming server supports multiple clients, your client can look like this:
//Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html
//untested code
class client{

 .....
 ....

 private static Socket echoSocket;

 //main can be in another class also
 public static void main(.... args[]){

   client nodeI,nodeII;
   nodeI = new client("speaker/sender");
   nodeII = new client("listener/recvr");
   nodeI.connect2Server();
   nodeI.sendMssgInstr2Server(node);

 }

 public void connect2Server(){

  try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("<jms.srvr.ip>", <port#>);                         
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: <jms.srvr.ip>.");
            System.exit(1);
        } 
 }

 public void sendMssgInstr2Server throws IOException (client RecipientClientNodeII){
   out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
   out.println("sending message:"+mssgQueue.poll() + " =>recipient client is now reading:"+RecipientClientNodeII.receive);
 }

public void receive(){
  try{
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream())); 
       }catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "+"the connection to: <jms.srvr.ip>.");
            System.exit(1);
     }

  while(1) 
    in.readLine();
 }

//other methods
  .......
  .......

}; //class client ends
```

Comment: hope this helps :) Please let me know if I got ur question all wrong :P

Comment: Hi MazakiyaDeciphered, why do you use such a low level connection as Socket? And in your example you are using 3 instances of "client". Why?